# How to open a menu SubItem with an actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, menuitem, tabitem, action-button

I'm developing my first shiny app and I want to put some buttons on the mainPage that redirect to the menu subItens I've created.

I tried to do this using the menu subItens link, but it didn't work. So, I copied the code I used to do the menu subItens and put it in the actionButton code. It works well, but just on the first click. I need to reload the page to the button work again.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?

**Here is the menuSubItem code**

```
sidebarMenu( id = "tabs",
          menuItem("Conjuntura", tabName = "conjuntura", icon = icon("chart-bar"),
                   menuSubItem("Visão Geral",
                               tabName = "visao_geral"),
                   menuSubItem("Atividade Econômica",
                               tabName = "atividade_economica"),
dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          # tab visão geral
          tabItem(
            tabName = "visao_geral",
            mod_conj_titulo_ui("titulo_ui_1")
          ),
          # tab conjuntura
          tabItem(
            tabName = "atividade_economica",
            mod_conj_atividade_economica_ui("atividade_economica_ui_1"),
            mod_conj_atividade_economica_es_ui("atividade_economica_es_ui_1")
            )
```

**Here is the button code**

```
actionButton(inputId = "atividade_economica", 
                 label = menuSubItem(HTML("<br>Atividade<br>Econômica"),
                                     tabName = "atividade_economica", 
                                     icon = icon("chart-line", class = "icon")),
                 class = "button"
                 )
```

I didn't put anything in the server to run the button. I think that that's the problem.

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce the issue and shows how you are using the `actionButton`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to rely on the anyways loaded `bootstrap` JavaScript library, to handle the toggling for you. Thus, you just need to place a `<a>` tag somewhere, which has the appropriate `data-toggle` and `data-value` attributes properly set.

Some additional JavaScript to properly highlight the selected tab in the menu bar makes the whole approahc round:

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

js <- HTML(paste("$(() => $('.mimic-menu').on('click', function() {",
                 "   const menu_item = $(this).data('value');",
                 "   const $parent = $('.sidebar-menu [data-value=\"' + menu_item + '\"]').closest('li');",
                 "   $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');",
                 "   $parent.addClass('active');",
                 "}));", sep = "\n"))

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
   sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets", badgeLabel = "new",
               badgeColor = "green"),
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
      )
   )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
   tags$head(tags$script(js)),
   tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard",
              div(p("Dashboard tab content"))
      ),
      tabItem("widgets",
              "Widgets tab content",
              tags$a(href = "#shiny-tab-dashboard", `data-toggle` = "tab",
                     class = "btn btn-default mimic-menu",
                     `data-value` = "dashboard", "Click to go to dashboard")
      ),
      tabItem("subitem1",
              "Sub-item 1 tab content",
              tags$a(href = "#shiny-tab-dashboard", `data-toggle` = "tab",
                     class = "btn btn-default mimic-menu",
                     `data-value` = "dashboard", "Click to go to dashboard")
      ),
      tabItem("subitem2",
              "Sub-item 2 tab content",
              tags$a(href = "#shiny-tab-dashboard", `data-toggle` = "tab",
                     class = "btn btn-default mimic-menu",
                     `data-value` = "dashboard", "Click to go to dashboard")
      )
   )
)

shinyApp(
   ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
   server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

### Explanation

- All we need to do is to use an `<a>` tag, which sets the attributes `data-toggle = "tab"` and `data-value = <name of the tab we want to switch to>`.
- Then, bootstrap does the switching for us automagically.
- However, this leads to the unclean state that the last selected menu item in the sidebar is highlighted, even if we switched the tab.
- Thus, we add some custom JavaScript which reacts on clicks on the self-made links to select the proper item in the sidebar menu.
- To give the link the look and feel of a button, we add the `btn` and `btn-default` class. The `mimic-menu` class is functional, to allow for triggering the aforementioned code.

### Screenshot

[image: GIF showing the click change event]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it didn't work. The button works, but it opens a blank link.

Comment: Well, without a minimal working example it will be difficult to tell. The example I showed, works on my PC at least. I will add a gif to show.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm really new at this and I'm still learning how to do things.